# Elasticsearch query to return limited amount of result (10) which will contain 2 from each specified keyword

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have articles stored in Elasticsearch and I've been wondering if there is a way I can query by date but the result to contain a specific amount of articles from each publisher. More specifically, I have 5 different publishers and I want to get the 10 latest articles, 2 from each publisher. I'm storing the publishers name as a keyword field in elastic.

The only idea I've come up with is to run a query for each publisher separately and limit the result to the first 2 (and then merge the results programmatically), but it will be more efficient I think if there is way I can do this in a single query.

Thanks

Comment: you should share how to document is indexed (mapping with example)

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a case for [field collapsing](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/collapse-search-results.html#expand-collapse-results).

You would `collapse` on the `publisher` field (as long as it is a keyword or a number) and then request `inner_hits`, the actual articles.